# How to manually import a type from an index.d.ts file, and tell VS Code intellisense that a variable is of that type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have the following problem: I'm building some program based on Express.js(using plain JS, not TS).
I'm using Sequelize as an ORM.

I have "repository" classes, which inherit functionality from a BaseRepository class. This is an example UserRepo:

```
   class UserRepo extends BaseRepo{
        constructor(model){
            super(model);
        }    
    }
```

The parent class, BaseRepo:

```
class BaseRepo{

    constructor(model){//VSCODE HAS NO CLUE WHAT TYPE THAT IS
        this.model = model
    }
    async index(){
        const records = await this.model.findAll();
        return records;
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem is that VSCode doesn't know that this.model is a **Sequelize model**, being that it gets injected elsewhere. Therefore, intellisense doesn't work.

Is there any way to manually import the model type declaration, and tell VSCode to use it, perhaps using JSDoc?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Typescript, set the Type in the constructor like so

```
constructor(model: Sequelize){
    this.model = model
}
```

If you're using Javascript, write the JSDocs like so:

```
/**
 * @param {Sequelize} model
 */
constructor(model){
    this.model = model
}
```

Comment: Yes but i wasn't sure how to actually import that type(seems it's impossible to import TS types when you're using JS). What worked eventually is importing directly the Model from 'sequelize/lib/model'